# Location of essential loadout and gun fire rate in cube2 sauerbraten

Tags: ubuntu

I want to add a cheat to cube2 sauerbraten that allows the delay between pistol rifle and shotgun shots shorter, and to make my loadout be max. Where are the files that control that found? What are the file's names? I am running Ubuntu 21.10.  I looked around in /usr/share/games/sauerbraten for the right file, but I didn't find the right one there.  I also looked in /home/administrator/.sauerbraten and I did not find it there either.  Where is it?? (I asked this queston on arqade, but nobody gave me a comment or answer.)

Comment: While this question is on topic here since it is about using a piece of software under Linux, you will probably have better chances of getting an answer on the Steam Forums or any other site dedicated to gaming.

Comment: I am not using it with steam.  I will look for such a forum though.

Comment: @terdon the question would be the same if the OP used Windows

Comment: @jsotola perhaps, but I don't see how that's relevant. There are a few programs that exist for both nix and windows and questions about using such software _on a nix system_ would be on topic. The fact that the tools also run on windows isn't relevant as long as this question is about using them on nix.

Comment: @terdon my thinking is that it may belong at SO

Comment: I asked this on some other gaming forums.  nobody said anything at all.

Comment: What makes you think there is such a file?  You'll need to examine the source code to confirm that.  Most likely, you'll need to modify the source and recompile it to do what you want, or write a mod.  Fortunately, it's an open source game so the source code is available.  You can find a link to the sourceforge page at http://sauerbraten.org/ and it's easy to find github mirrors of the source if you prefer git to svn (or just want to avoid sourceforge, which has a shady reputation due to their past association with spyware and other malware installers, although they have a new owner now).

Comment: @jsotola it would be completely off topic at SO, this has nothing to do with programming

Comment: @cas, there is a file that specifies every value in every game.  I just have to find it in whatever form it may be in.

Comment: You may believe that, or you may think it "makes sense" for such a file to exist, but you are mistaken and are suffering from some kind of wishful thinking.  Not every game has a config file. And very few games that do have a config file have one that specifies *every* value in the game.   Most game values are compiled into the game's executable and can only be changed by editing the source code and recompiling or find the exact location in the compiled executable and using a hex editor or binary patching tool.

Comment: that's what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the properties of the guns are defined in the source code of the game and are not modifiable at runtime. The file is [src/fpsgame/game.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/sauerbraten/code/HEAD/tree/src/fpsgame/game.h). Look for `static const struct guninfo` starting at line #348.

The same file also defines the `struct fpsstate` data structure, which includes the ammo counts for each gun, and the maximum ammo values are defined in `static struct itemstat` also in the same file.

Since Sauerbraten has multiplayer functionality, it is split into client and server components. Although in a single-player mode both the client and server are on the same computer, they may still be separate entities within the game program.

In [src/fpsgame/entities.cpp](https://sourceforge.net/p/sauerbraten/code/HEAD/tree/src/fpsgame/entities.cpp) there are functions `addammo()` and `repammo()`, and there is this comment near them:

> ```
> // these two functions are called when the server acknowledges that you really
> // picked up the item (in multiplayer someone may grab it before you).
> ```

So it looks like in order to increase your ammo counts, you'd need to somehow convince the server component that you've just picked up some ammo.

If you are serious about this, you will need to download the source code package for the game. Go to "Ubuntu Software Center" -> Edit -> Software Sources, and make sure the "Source code" is selected on the "Ubuntu Software" tab. You will have to enter your password to make any changes here. Then you can close the window, open a command prompt window, make yourself an empty work directory, `cd` into it, and run `apt-get source cube2`. It should automatically download the source code of the game engine for you into that work directory. There will be a sub-directory `fpsgame`, which will contain the `game.h` file.

You will also want to run `sudo apt build-dep cube2` to install the tools and libraries needed to recompile the game engine from the source.

Then, you should first try and build the game engine without any changes, just to verify that you have all the pieces in place to do it. The simplest way to do it is probably to run `debuild -b -uc -us` in your work directory. This will take a while and usually will produce a lot of messages. If successful, it should produce your own `*.deb` package of the game engine, which you could use to replace the currently-installed version. But there would be no point in doing that, because your package should be essentially identical to the installed version (apart from missing the cryptographic signature of an Ubuntu maintainer).

Once you have verified all of this works, you can start making changes and rebuilding. After each successful rebuild, you will have to install your modified `.deb` package in order to make your changes take effect in the actual game.

It looks like the game is written in the C++ programming language, so a basic understanding of it or some similar programming language will probably be necessary to figure out the structure of the game code and do anything meaningful with it.

Based on your question, you may not really know what you're doing. That's all right, you *can* learn by doing. But I must warn you, if you don't have any programming skills yet, this may be a much bigger challenge than you probably expect. Good luck.

Comment: changing the values there doesn't seem to affect a thing.

Comment: Those values control the monsters for the campaign.  Not me.

Comment: what command would you use to make a statement be always true, not just a in a "case"